# What are pros and cons of different social gaming networks from developer's point of view?

Tags: mobile, social

I am developing a game for a mobile platform and I want to integrate it with either **Scoreloop** or **Openfeint**.

So my question is which of the platforms has better SDK (by that I mean that its has better tools to implement achievements and global leader board and other things) and more features?

Which of those has larger user base?

Comment: I have neve heard of Scoreloop before this. I have a ton of OpenFeint games, however.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think anyone can give you a definitive answer to this one.

You need to weigh up a number of factors and rate them based on your projects requirements.

- Licence terms: Are you required to link/mention the provider?
- Features: leader boards weekly/monthly/etc, achievements, matchmaking, etc.
- Platform availability: iOS, Android, WinPhone7, and Web
- Service Performance: Do they place any limit on you that could affect the responsiveness of your game

If you can't choose sign up with both and see how easy it is to work with either of them.